# jquery datatable load on ajax success

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am a newbie and need a complete working example of loading and refreshing a jQuery datatable within an Ajax success call. I want to open a dialog with jquery datatable loaded in it. The dialog should open only when ajax result returns more than one records.

Here is the dialog HTML:

```
  <div id="rfrList" title="Referring Providers">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="rfrListTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="70%">Name</th>
          <th width="25%">NPI</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>        
  </div>
```

And here is my Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/ajax/rfr_list.php',
          data: {"name": name},
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
            var rfrRows = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(rfrRows.length == 1){
              $("#referring_text").val(rfrRows[0].name);
              $("#referring_npi").val(rfrRows[0].npi);
            }else{
              $( "#rfrList" ).dialog("open");
              var $rfrTable = $('#rfrListTable').dataTable( { bRetrieve : true } );
              $rfrTable.fnDraw(); // I need my ajax result in table now
            }
          }         
        });
```

I am not sure how to make my ajax result reach the datatable.

EDIT:
I can not see any result in table although my ajax call returns with many records.

Here is the PHP code returning data.

```
$stmt->set_qry_str($sql);
  $retval = $stmt->exec();
  if($retval === false){
//      toLogger
  }else{
    $rows = array();
    while($stmt->fetchAssocNext()){   // This function returns associative array
      $rows[] = $stmt->get_resultRow();
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
  }
```

And Here is the firebug snapshot of response.

[{"npi":"1","name":"Stan, XXX"},{"npi":"1212121212","name":"Stanley, YYY"},{"npi":"0123456789","name":"Schaeffer Scott S"}]

Comment: is there any problems now ?

Comment: Yes, my code does not bring anything in table though I can see result records in firebug.

Comment: you mean you receive empty answer ?

Comment: Yes dialog opens with empty table and places where I expect rows says: No data available in table. BTW data returned by my php file is printing mysql results using json_encode.

Comment: please show php code responsible for ajax answer

Comment: I have edited my question with PHP code.